# Ошибка отображения JSP страницы

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring-boot, jsp

При отображении JSP страницы столкнулся с такой проблемой:

```
2021-12-04 22:40:14.595 ERROR 22068 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/].[jsp]        : Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:54) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:294) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:81) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTldResourcePath(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:251) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:122) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:435) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:493) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1450) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:144) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:244) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:105) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:351) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:605) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
```

Не пойму как ее решить.
Вот мой pom:

```
...
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>8.0.25</mysql.connector.version>
    <jsonwebtoken.version>0.9.1</jsonwebtoken.version>
    <modelmapper.version>2.4.4</modelmapper.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Сама страница:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>


<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Rooms</title>
    <link href="./css/styleRoom1.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="index-mine">
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Номер комнаты</th>
        <th>Цена за ночь</th>
        <th>Доступность</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="room-table-body">
    <c:forEach var="rooms" items="${roomsList}">
        <tr>
            <td>${rooms.id}</td>
            <td>${rooms.price}</td>
            <td>${rooms.underRenovation}?'Комната на ремонте' : 'Доступно'</td>
        </tr>

    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Приложение конфигурирую через java. web.xml нет. Вот структура проекта: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что может быть не так?

Answer (score 0):

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri:
> [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in
> either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this
> application

Наверно ошибка здесь, поскольку используются различные версии JSTL библиотеки. В зависимости от версии Servlet API, надо использовать только одну версию.

```xml
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
     <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.6</version
 </dependency>
```